# Python program to get value from different dataframe with same row name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe

```
Name    Value1
IJK     127
LMN     987
PQR     678
```

And other as

```
Name    Value2
IJK     45
LMN     7
PQR     67
KPI     988
```

How can I create new dataframe

```
Name    Value2    Value1
IJK     45        127
LMN     7         987
PQR     67        678
KPI     988
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

If both have `Name` as column:

```
df.merge(df2, on="Name", how="outer")
```

If both have `Name` as index:

```
df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a merge:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='outer')
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).